# Continue a cancelled download

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have a question regarding on how mobile OSs such as iOS and Android work regarding a cancelled download. I was wondering if there is any guaranteed way to restore a download from the point where it was cancelled. 
I do understand that for instance iOS does not provide access to its temporary downloaded files, but you could continue a download as long as you were using

```
cancel(byProducingResumeData ..)
```

However, there is no guarantee that the **resumed** **data** will still be available at the moment you start the download again. Furthermore, there is an overload in storing this checkpoint in case the app is terminated meanwhile.

I was wondering if there is a way to provide some sort of custom **URLCache** to the **URLSessionConfiguration** so that the temporary files of a download are stored at a location (on disk maybe) where it is certain to have access if you try to start the download again. 
Same question for Android: is the data flushed on cancel or there is a nice controlled way to go back to it?